# How can I test two int lists in Python against each other for similarities and if the similarities indexes are in equivilant order throughout?

Tags: python, list

Below is a condensed version of what i have done so far. I feel I am very close to fix this. I get an output telling me that "ValueError: 0 is not in list"

```
la = [] # list a
lb = [] # list b`

for i in range(len(la)):
    for j in range(len(lb)):
        if lb[j] in la and lb.index(j) >= la.index(i): #THIS LINE!!!
            print ("yes")
        else:
            print ("no")
```

Thanks in advance and beyond!

Comment: FYI - the for loops are supposed to be nested

Comment: `index` expects a list element as argument, and returns the index of the first occurrence of such element. You are searching for an index itself when you put `lb.index(j)`. It should read `lb.index(lb[j])`, or simply `j` because j is already the index.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your list? And a better explanation of what you need to compare: Do both lists have to contain the common elements in the same order? Can there be elements that belong only to one of the lists?

Comment: Example lists would be `A = [1,2,3,4,5] B= [3.8.5.6.7] ` I am looking for elements of B occur in A in the order
they appear in B but not necessarily consecutively.  for now it is jst between two lists.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a bug in line

```
lb.index(j) >= la.index(i)
```

here `j` is index which starts with 0. `lb.index(j)` means you are looking for 0 in array `lb`. Which when not present will give you the error you have shared `ValueError: 0 is not in list`.

Probably you are looking for something like this.

```
la = [1] # list a
lb = [1] # list b`

for i in range(len(la)):
    for j in range(len(lb)):
        if lb[j] in la and j >= i:
            print ("yes")
        else:
            print ("no")
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas for you help.Appriciated.  I will give it a go in a bit and see how i get on.

Comment: @MC_Nyquist Np :) Also if the solution works then see if you can accept this answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the clarifications you made of your requirements, consider the following:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = [3, 8, 5, 6, 7]

prev_idx_a = 0  # you need a way to check if indexes in list A increment each time
for idx_b, b in enumerate(B):
    if b in A:
        idx_a = A.index(b)
        if idx_a > prev_idx_a:  # make sure the order is not inverted
            prev_idx_a = idx_a  
        else:
            print("No") # or return a -1, raise an exception, etc...
```

There is no output if the check is successful, only if it fails.

Now, consider that there could be duplicates, even when preserving the order:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = [3, 8, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

All the "3" come before the "5", but the code above will fail. You'd need to add another condition to test only the first occurrence:

```
prev_idx_a = 0
prev_b = None
for idx_b, b in enumerate(B):
    if b in A:
        if b != prev_b:  # check only first occurrence
            prev_b = b
            idx_a = A.index(b)
            if idx_a > prev_idx_a:
                prev_idx_a = idx_a
            else:
                print("No")
```